# Data frame encoding problems and Excel write problems in Crawling

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

This is Korea cosmetics website crawler :)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import pandas as pd
import os

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/webdrivers/chromedriver')
url = "http://naturecollection.co.kr/product/view.jsp?dpid=AF005186"
driver.get(url)
sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
sub_en = sel.xpath('//*[@class="section fr"]//*[@class="subTit"]/text()').extract()
description = sel.xpath('//*[@id="proExplain"]//p').extract()
image_urls = sel.xpath('//*[@class="thumList"]/li/a/img/@src').extract()
options = sel.xpath('//*[@class="colorChip optionList"]//@title').extract()
result = []
for idx, option in enumerate(options):
    prod = ({
        'Option': option,
        'Url': url,
        'Description': description,
        'Image_urls': image_urls
    })

    result.append(prod)

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/export/result_lg.xlsx',
                        options={'strings_to_urls': False}, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='result', startrow=0, columns=['Option', 'Url', 'Description', 'Image_urls'], encoding='utf-8')
writer.save()
driver.close()
driver.stop_client()
```

However, the following problems occur when writing to Excel.

description

```
['<p align="center" style="text-align: center;"><img alt="" src="http://image.lgcare.com/naturecollectionWebSrc/upload/smeditor//2016/1477294435929.jpg"></p>', '<p>\xa0</p>', '<p align="center" style="text-align: center;">\xa0</p>', '<p>\xa0</p>', '<p align="center" style="text-align: center;"><br style="clear: both;">\xa0</p>', '<p align="center" style="text-align: center;">\xa0</p>', '<p>\xa0</p>']

--->  \xa0 , [' , '] , ', '


  --->  \t\t\t\t\n' , \n (In other descriptions, things like left are also generated.)
```

I don't need these, but they happen all the time. when written by pandas

when write a xlrd is good.
The result that I want is as follows.(this is written by xlrd)

description

```
<p align="center" style="text-align: center;"><img alt="" src="http://image.lgcare.com/naturecollectionWebSrc/upload/smeditor//2016/1477294435929.jpg"></p><p> </p><p align="center" style="text-align: center;"> </p><p> </p><p align="center" style="text-align: center;"><br style="clear: both;"> </p><p align="center" style="text-align: center;"> </p><p> </p>
```

I wonder why this happens.  I would like to use pandas for convenience. 
is there any solution?
thank you very much.

Comment: What happens if you change `engine='xlsxwriter'` to `engine='xlrd'`?

Comment: ValueError: No Excel writer 'xlrd'  -- occured